# На странице аналитики (при нехватке репутации) вместо “аналитики” упоминаются “статистика”

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии, аналитика-сайта

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить на "доступ к аналитике сайта".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/9899

Заменил на:

> доступ к аналитике сайта